# how to create a vpn software

Tags: c#, c++, networking, network-programming

I want to create an application which creates a VPN between some endpoints, something like [hamachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi) and i do not have a starting point. I haven't found any resource to explain how to create such a network application.I want to use c# because i have some experience with it.
I really need some help, anything that can put me on the right way. Thanks.

Comment: Try this first http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vpn for options, then select which one you want, then explore that option.

Comment: I think you want to give this wiki link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogMeIn_Hamachi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of distinct elements of VPN software that you'll have to figure out:

- What technology/standard will your program use to provide the privacy? Some common ones are IPSEC, L2TP, PPTP, SSH, and SSL. Web searches ought to turn up rich information (including RFCs) on all of these. If you're doing this as a learning exercise, rather than needing actual security, you could also design your own.
- Are you implementing a client, a server, or both?
- What operating system(s) will you support?  This affects what you need to do to convince it to route packets through your application.
- Do you plan to interoperate with software implementing some standard?

Comment: Well, i am doing this as a learning exercise. So choosing the  standard to provide the privacy seems to be the first stage if i get that right.
I will create(hopefully) both client and server and it will be made for windows.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at SSH tunneling and see if it solves your needs.

Comment: or something else that is already made.. there is tons of VPN software that is free/opensource